# Subscribe to multiple observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I want to subscribe to multiple observables but the second observable depends on the first one. So from the first one I get a customer id and I need to get all the information from a new observable.

```
this.taskService
      .get(this.$state.params.taskId)
      .pipe(
        switchMap((taskDetails: IGetTask) => this.taskService.getAgreement(taskDetails.taskParameters.customerAgreementId)),
        tap(customerAgreement => this.customerAgreement = customerAgreement)
      )
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.signees = new SignatoryDetails(data);
        this.customerDetails = new CustomerDetails(data);
      });
```

This is my current code but I don't know how to proceed adding the new observer for getting the customer information. Customer id is present in this.customerAgreement. I can get the customer information by this.customerService.getCustomer(ID).

Comment: So where's the second Observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just `switchMap` again? Do you need both, the customer agreement, and the customer information in your subscribe? Then, you should map the result of the first observable onto the result of the second observable using `map`.

Here is an example:

```
this.taskService
    .get(this.$state.params.taskId)
    .pipe(
        switchMap((taskDetails: IGetTask) => this.taskService.getAgreement(taskDetails.taskParameters.customerAgreementId)),
        tap(customerAgreement => this.customerAgreement = customerAgreement),
        switchMap(customerAgreement => this.customerService.getCustomer(customerAgreement.id).pipe(
            map(customerInformation => ({customerInformation: customerInformation, customerAgreement: customerAgreement}))))
    )
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
        let customerAgreement = data.customerAgreement;
        let customerInformation = data.customerInformation;

        this.signees = new SignatoryDetails(data);
        this.customerDetails = new CustomerDetails(data);
    });
```

Comment: Thnx for you input, it makes sense but when I try to implement it I get an error that property id not exists on type object (in this.customerService.getCustomer(customerAgreement.id))

Comment: that's because I don't know where you are storing id on customerAgreement. You wrote: "Customer id is present in this.customerAgreement". Where is it present?

Comment: Sorry my bad. It is working now. Thnx for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to zip your input with output inside switchMap:

```
switchMap((taskDetails: IGetTask) =>
        Observable.zip(this.taskService.getAgreement(taskDetails.taskParameters.customerAgreementId),
                        Observable.Of(taskDetails.taskParameters.customerAgreementId)))
```